# sell application source code without Keystore

Tags: android, code-signing, keystore, keytool, android-keystore

I have an signed android app currently published in online Markets.
I have used always the same keystore for all published app.

i want to sell this app source.
Such as when Facebook bought Instagram app.

what should I do? 
How buyer publish it without my signature?

**NOTE:**
i am iranian and iranian market is [cafebazar](http://cafebazaar.ir/?l=en).
(Google [GooglePlay] has sanctioned Iranian people and we use cafebazar)
This store isn't allowed to upload similar app (If the package name changed again detect Similarity from code Similarity )

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can sell without keystore. But the buyer have to publish in other package name, other account not where you published.

But if you want to sell your place too, keystore need to be included in. Because, users cannot update app with different sign.

Comment: i am iranian and iranian market is cafebazar ... This store is not allowed to upload similar app (If the package name changed again detect Similarity from code Similarity )